# How to convert diacritical words to text in browser using C# .NET (UTF-8/Unicode)?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-2

The Web Page I work on, for example, takes the county from where a certain person sends feedback (because the site is an ad site, like `ebay` or `aliexpress`) and appears in an NPS (Net Promoter Score (NPS) is a customer loyalty and satisfaction measurement taken from asking customers how likely they are to recommend your product or service to others on a scale of 0-10) . In the database, for example, the county appears correctly written with diacritics, but when it is also displayed in browsers on the NPS page (the page where only the admin can see what review the user gave, where he is from, and what product category he was referring to), the special letters such as `á`, appears as `&#225`;

When I try to add Hungarian words such as `Állat, növény` in the browser, special letters `(Á, ö, é, etc.)` appear with "Á" , `&#246;`, `&#233;`, `&#225;`. I tried different options looking for and reading among other similar situations, but none of them were useful for me to have those special letters in my browser. Below I will attach the code used. Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Could it be a problem elsewhere? At the server, the database, or somewhere else that I'm not aware of?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` but it didn't work

In the `applicationUser.County` are the words that contain different special letters

```
    //The first option I tried

    //byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(applicationUser.County);
    //string str1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

    //The second option I tried

    Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2");
    Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
    byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(applicationUser.County);
    byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
    string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
    County = msg;

    //The third option I tried

    //string msg = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(applicationUser.County));
```

Here is a picture of the result I get in that NPS
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "add Hungarian words in the browser"? Please give us more context - we have no idea what kind of application you're writing. But treating UTF-8-encoding text as if it's encoded in a different encoding is almost *certainly* going to lose data. With more context, ideally a [mcve], we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet, the program I work on, for example, takes the county from where a certain person sends feedback (because the site is an ad site) and appears in an NPS. In the database, for example, the county appears correctly written with diacritics, but when it is also displayed in browsers on the NPS page, the special letters such as `á`, appears as `&#225;`

Comment: What is "an NPS" here? Again, we don't have enough context. Is "the program you work on" a web application, or something else? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to make it *much* clearer.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `HtmlDecode` twice? Using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` gave me the expected result, see this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MfgAdD

Comment: @silkfire I also tried the version specified by you, but it didn't work and I saw in another topic that I should wrapp it twice in HtmlDecode but still didn't work

Comment: @JonSkeet I have edited the question. Hope now it's more clear

Comment: Perhaps your data actually contains *other* characters or some invisible characters?

Comment: I would suggest hard-coding the data temporarily, to take the database out of the picture. Basically, sort it so that you can display the data when it's correct, then you can work on getting the data right to start with.

Comment: Just as an update, I saw that the letter `ű` appears correctly and not like the others like for exemple `&#233;`. I really don't know how to make it work the same on other letters. I didn't make anything, yet that letter `ű` appears correctly and not as an HTML entity